# mail() sometimes not working, problem in sendmail parameter

Tags: php, debian, sendmail

The mail() function in php works strange these days.

```
<?php
mail("email@mail.com", "Subject", "Content");
?>
```

The above script works if I use "php script.php" in command line.
However, if I link to the page(http://domain.com/script.php) by browser, the mail will not be sent even if the mail function returns true.

I googled about it and find a solution. It says "modify the php.ini file as following".

Change

sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

to

sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"

And it works for me right now. Does anyone know why removing parameter -i can solve the problem?
it goes well with -i in the past few months!!

Answer (score 0):

From the [sendmail manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail):

> -i Ignore dots alone on lines by themselves in incoming messages. This
>   should be set if you are reading data from a file.

So it may depend on how the content is formatted, or how mail() internally decides to read the content and then feed it to sendmail (were previous versions of mail() writing the content string in a temporary file and then calling sendmail?).

Comment: I'm curious about why typing in the command(php script.php) is different from retrieve from apache(http://domain.com/script.php).

Comment: When you issue -i, sendmail waits for end-of-file.